# iCloud catching malware

Tags: macos, icloud, malware

I had a discussion with a friend of mine today about Malware and iCloud. I am absolutely unexperienced in Software and Security so maybe all of this is absolutely impossible.

Its very simple. Let's assume my MacBook catches Malware (Virus, Keyloggers, or any spyware). Could this sneak into my iCloud and hide there? And after resetting my MacBook and connecting to my Apple ID again this could infect the device again? Or even infect other devices within the same Apple ID...

I am kind of worried about this now.

Comment: Are you asking "is it theoretically possible", or "is it likely", or "are there any known instances"??

Comment: Well I would ask if it is likely which would mean there should be known instances... Maybe you have some experience in software and or security and you could tell me well this is nonsense soo yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The risk is extremely low that iCloud will have any impact on a virus or malware.

A far more likely scenario is that the virus reads your personal data. However, this would be equally likely with or without iCloud.

In general, just make sure not to install any software you don't trust. This is overwhelmingly the most likely way to get malware / viruses. Actual "viruses" that install themselves without your permission are rare and typically reserved for high-stakes targeted attacks.

Note: it is technically possible that a file could be saved to iCloud drive and somehow facilitate a virus transmitting itself. However the requirements for this to happen would involve widespread hacking and compromises that will impact far more than just your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Apple spends a lot of time making sure that its operating systems are as secure as possible (though that's not to say that they are perfect).

First of all, iOS and iPadOS are very secure, because you can't install apps from anywhere outside the App Store, where Apple has checked them.

MacOS is more flexible, but it also has lots of secure features. The risk of getting malware is very low.

But: the biggest point of failure in any computer system is .... you.

If you download software from "less than legitimate" websites; if you willingly provide your password authorisation, or click through "OK" dialogs, without thinking what you are being asked, and why; if you click on links in email, messages, and the web that don't look entirely 'right': then you increase your risk significantly.

Above all, make sure you have a good, local backup on an external drive, so that in the event of something going wrong, you can restore your files or restore your entire disk to a hopefully clean state. (iCloud Drive is not a backup.)

As to whether malware could spread across iCloud. As said, most malware doesn't spread itself like Hollywood viruses. They rely on users accidentally installing them, without knowing what it is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Of course in the end you and I as the user are responsible. But if even if theoretically something would sneak its way into the macbook (via homebrew casks for example), it is still almost impossible that such a crazy thing exists which could travels through clouds and devices you would assume? So no need to worry about something like that